# How do you get Varnish to serve cached objects with an expired TTL when the backend returns 503?

Tags: cache, varnish

I'm trying to get Varnish to serve up cached objects with an expired TTL when requesting a new copy of the object from the backend returns a 503 error.

There is a [Varnish Grace feature](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleGrace) which will do this when the backend is *unhealthy*, but it doesn't work when the backend is passing its health check.

Answer (score 4):

That's where saint mode comes in - you can use it to mark the backend's response as unusable, and start the request over again, either using a different backend or stale content from grace mode.

```
if (beresp.status == 503) {
  set beresp.saintmode = 10s;
  return(restart);
}
```